# Salesforce docusign Iframe Error

Tags: javascript, salesforce, runtime-error, docusignapi

I am  Getting below error message, when trying to access through the custom button from salesforce in service cloud console and non admin. I integrated the docusign package.

Error :
**Javascript proxies were not generated for controlled dsfs.EnvelopeController: may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe**

The same code was working fine with the Docusign previous release,  issue is with in new release.

Error Image Url : https://community.docusign.com/docusign/attachments/docusign/DocuSignforSalesforce/1047/1/error.PNG

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time reach out regarding this issue.

The current version of DocuSign for Salesforce (6.0) does not support the Salesforce Console view. Our engineers are aware of this issue and are actively working on a solution

Comment: I have another customer not using Service Cloud and receive this same error message. No error when on version 5.6 of the managed package. Started as soon as it was upgraded to 6.2.

Comment: Please see: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-admin-guide/Content/admin-guide/console-buttons.htm