# Docusign for Salesforce: Lightning Component: Javascript proxies error (may not use public remoted methods inside an iFrame)

Tags: javascript, iframe, docusignapi

As per the ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259467/salesforce-docusign-iframe-error/48115781#48115781), I too am receiving the following error, this time when going from a Lightning Component to the standard Send with Docusign page, from Standard Salesforce Quotes. The error only appears once the document has been sent for signature and before it reaches the confirmation screen (it reaches the screen once you close the error):

```
An embedded page at pracedo--dsfs.eu11.visual.force.com says:

Javascript proxies were not generated for controller dsfs.EnvelopeController: may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe.
```

I have created a helper class to try to determine if it is in an iFrame and go by another means, but it doesn't seem to behave any differently:

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >

<div class="slds-text-body_regular">Have you already created the Quote PDF?   </div>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Yes - Send with DocuSign" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />

</aura:component>
```

Component Controller:

```
({
    handleClick : function (component, event, helper) {
        // Variables for URL
        var sourceId = component.get("v.recordId");
        // check if in an iFrame and go to url
        if(helper.inIframe()){
            window.open("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0 &SourceID="+sourceId+"&RQD="+sourceId , "Popup", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, directories=1, toolbar=1, titlebar=1, width=1200");
        } else {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
            "url":"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0 &SourceID="+sourceId+"&RQD="+sourceId , "isredirect": "true"
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }
    }
})
```

Component Helper:

```
({
    inIframe : function() {
  try {
     return !(window===window.parent);
        } catch (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

Everything works except this annoying error! Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Any help or guidance would be fantastic.

Cheers, Tom

Answer (score -1):

I think this error prompted at the front browser is caused by an annotation @RemoteAction in your controller which is referenced by your visualforce page,
at the same time,you included this vf page in an iframe.
   So you should separete the static @RemoteAction method from your cf controller class.

Thanks
Kenta